# How to resolve "mismatched types" error while ink_e2e test : expected String, found Vec<u8>

Tags: ink, smart-contract, testing, e2e

I am working with `ink_e2e` testing framework in ink smart contract, and I have encountered an error message that's a bit confusing. The error says: `mismatched types - expected String, found Vec<u8>`. However, I am certain that I am passing a `String` and not a `Vec<u8>`. To provide more context, I have added a screenshot of the relevant code snippet where the error occurs within the `ink_e2e` framework. Can someone help me understand why I'm getting this error when I am actually passing the expected type? Are there any nuances in the `ink_e2e` framework that might be causing this discrepancy?

[image]

Comment: could you also show the mint function of your contract?